# How to pull text from a shape in a Word document using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to grab the text from inside a shape on a Word document.

```
Sub textgrab()
  MsgBox ActiveDocument.Shapes("Rectangle 85").TextFrame.TextRange.Text
End Sub
```

I get the error:

> Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)':
>   The item with the specified name wasn't found.

In the Word document when I go to the top menu, hit the shape format tab, and in the arrange section, I select 'selection pane', I get a list of all the shapes, 'Rectangle 85' is there.

When I select it, it highlights the box i'm trying to grab the value from.

This is a pdf that I've opened in Word. I'm trying to automate a process that will open a pdf invoice, grab the dollar total, and pull it into Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for those that stumble upon this later.  I used the following:

ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages(1).Rectangles.Item(i).Range

Answer (score 0):

Word can only extract text from **Drawing objects**. These are inserted in the UI, for example, from `Insert/Shapes`. `Shape.TextFrame.TextRange` has no OCR capabilities, so can't be used to get text "embedded" in other kinds of graphic objects, such as an embedded PDF file or a JPG or anything similar.

When uncertain whether a particular `Shape` supports reading or writing text, right-click it in the UI and see if the menu selection `Add Text` or `Edit Text` is available.

Comment: Thanks for the info Cindy :)  I actually finally managed to grab the values from it by using the following:

ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages(1).Rectangles.Item(i).Range

Comment: @JonHolland Interesting... The discovery would deserve to go in an answer :-) Which on Stack Overflow you're allowed to write and then, after a couple of days, mark as "the" answer by clicking the checkmark at its left.

Comment: Alright, I've gone ahead and posted the answer as a separate item and pressed the green check.  Thanks for all your help!